# Which of the following is an eigenvector of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

So i just finished a linear algebra exam but because of technical issues im gonna do it again! I wanted to ask a question i found there! So if i remember it correctly the question goes like this:

There is a matrix \begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 & 3 & 2\\\ 0 & 4&0&0 \\ 5 &0 &0 &0\\ 0&0&0&0\end{pmatrix}

If i remember correctly this matrix is generated from the elementary basis e1,e2,e3,e4 with each being e1(1,0,0,0,),e2(0,1,0,0),e3(0,0,1,0) and e4(0,0,0,1) !

If i remember correctly the question was which of the elementary basis serves as an eigenvector of the matrix!

Can you help me understand **HOW** to solve this and if possible an answer of this particular problme! I probably have the exam tomorrow so i would be really helpful if you can help me!

Comment: Do you understand what an eigenvector is?

Comment: Can you give the images of the vectors $e_1$, $e_2$, $e_3$, $e_4$, when you apply the matrix to them ?

Comment: @Fimpellizieri i do know that to get an eigenvector you should do (A-λ**I**)=0

Comment: @TheSilverDoe If i remember correctly is the image taken from the multiplication of the matrix with one of the vectors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The punchline is that elementary basis vectors get acted upon by matrices in very predictable ways... namely it returns the corresponding column in the matrix.

The question is then, does there exist a column in the matrix which is a scalar multiple of its corresponding elementary basis vector?  The answer is yes... the second column is $4$ times the second elementary basis vector.

That is to say, $\begin{bmatrix}0&0&3&2\\0&4&0&0\\5&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}0\\4\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}=4\cdot \begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}$, the matrix acts on the vector the same way as scalar multiplication does on the vector.

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: so w8 by this logic also 5*(0,0,1,0) is an eigenvector right?

Comment: No.  The first column is not a multiple of the **first** elementary basis vector, it is the *third*.  First and third, they don't match.

Comment: so from what i got from what you told me! If i multiply the matrix by one of the elementary basis i should get something that goes like λe! You multiplied the matrix by the e2('0,1,0,0) and you got 4*(0,1,0,0) so by the same logic if I multiply The matrix with (0,0,1,0)i should get 5*(0,0,1,0) right?

Comment: No. If you multiply by e3 *you get the third column*. The third column (3,0,0,0) is not a multiple of the third elementary basis vector (0,0,1,0)!

Comment: ooooh i think i got it ty!